# Integrating phpmyadmin with Openstack Trove database as a service solution

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, cloud, openstack

I am looking for installing a private cloud using openstack. For dbaas part I chose trove. Because of the lack of any GUI (I am unable to ask clients to using trove via command line) I want to install phpmyadmin on another host and ask clients to connect to phpmyadmin for operations on their DBs. Unfortunately I could not manage to integrate trove and phpmyadmin. I am able to login to phpmyadmin panel via root mysql username but for other users, which are created in horizon, it is not possible. Would you please guide me through integrating phpmyadmin or another gui for using operations on trove?

Best regards.

Comment: Could they use MySQL workbench instead? It's better than PHPMyAdmin IMO.

Comment: Every solution would be nice but my problem is integrating that solution with trove.